# Stored procedure redundant data and sorting challenge

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I've got a stored procedure with a pivot where data fields become columns. Data that is presently returned has some redundancies and would like to see if there is a way to correct this. The stored procedure is actually feeding a `.rdlc` report and current output looks like this:

```
Period | No Of Interim | Excellent | Very Good | Good | Satisfactory | Unsatisfactory 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                                                    1 
12                                            1 
18                   1
18                               1 
18                                                                  1 
19                                                                                  1
19                                                   1 
2                    1 
2                                1
```

This is what it needs to look like:

```
Period | No Of Interim | Excellent | Very Good | Good | Satisfactory | Unsatisfactory 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                                                    1 
2                    1           1
12                                            1 
18                   1           1                                  1 
19                                                   1                              1
```

Period column needs to sorted in ascending fashion and repeating instances need to be added to the same line.

The stored procedure and corresponding view responsible for output is as follows:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT '],[' + [Description] 
    FROM vQualScoringGrade 
    GROUP BY [Description] 
    ORDER BY MAX([orderby]), [Description] 
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1,2,'') + ']'

SET @query = N'SELECT Period, ' + @cols + ' FROM 
(SELECT Period, Description, Value, OrderBy FROM 
vQualScoringGrade) p
PIVOT (SUM([Value]) for [Description] IN ( ' + @cols + ' )) AS pvt ORDER BY Period'

execute(@query)
end

SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT Period, Description, GradeCount AS Value, OrderBy
FROM (SELECT CASE CHARINDEX('.', Number) WHEN 0 THEN Number ELSE 
     REPLACE(LEFT(Number, CHARINDEX('.', Number)), '.', '') 
     END AS Period, 'NoOfInterim' AS Description, COUNT(Number) AS 
        GradeCount, 1 AS OrderBy
FROM vQualScoringExcellent AS vQualScoringExcellent
     GROUP BY Number, Description
UNION
SELECT CASE CHARINDEX('.', Number) WHEN 0 THEN Number ELSE 
     REPLACE(LEFT(Number, CHARINDEX('.', Number)), '.', '') 
     END AS Period, 'Excellent' AS Description, COUNT(Description) AS 
        GradeCount, 2 AS OrderBy
FROM vQualScoringExcellent AS vQualScoringExcellent_1
     GROUP BY Number, Description
UNION
SELECT CASE CHARINDEX('.', Number) WHEN 0 THEN Number ELSE 
     REPLACE(LEFT(Number, CHARINDEX('.', Number)), '.', '') 
     END AS Period, 'VeryGood' AS Description, COUNT(Description) AS 
        GradeCount, 3 AS OrderBy
FROM vQualScoringVeryGood AS vQualScoringVeryGood
     GROUP BY Number, Description
UNION
SELECT CASE CHARINDEX('.', Number) WHEN 0 THEN Number ELSE 
      REPLACE(LEFT(Number, CHARINDEX('.', Number)), '.', '') 
      END AS Period, 'Good' AS Description, COUNT(Description) AS 
         GradeCount, 4 AS OrderBy
FROM vQualScoringGood AS vQualScoringGood
      GROUP BY Number, Description
UNION
SELECT CASE CHARINDEX('.', Number) WHEN 0 THEN Number ELSE 
     REPLACE(LEFT(Number, CHARINDEX('.', Number)), '.', '') 
     END AS Period, 'Satisfactory' AS Description, COUNT(Description) AS 
        GradeCount, 5 AS OrderBy
FROM vQualScoringSatisfactory AS vQualScoringSatisfactory
     GROUP BY Number, Description
UNION
SELECT CASE CHARINDEX('.', Number) WHEN 0 THEN Number ELSE 
     REPLACE(LEFT(Number, CHARINDEX('.', Number)), '.', '') 
     END AS Period, 'Unsatisfactory' AS Description, COUNT(Description) AS 
        GradeCount, 6 AS OrderBy
FROM vQualScoringUnsatisfactory AS vQualScoringUnsatisfactory
     GROUP BY Number, Description) AS QualScoringGrade
ORDER BY OrderBy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that the problem is due to the `OrderBy` column in your PIVOT query. This line is the cause of your problem:

```
SELECT Period, Description, Value, OrderBy
```

I would alter the query to be:

```
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT '],[' + [Description] 
    FROM vQualScoringGrade 
    GROUP BY [Description] 
    ORDER BY MAX([orderby]), [Description] 
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1,2,'') + ']'

SET @query = N'SELECT Period, ' + @cols + ' 
               FROM 
               (
                  SELECT Period, Description, Value
                  FROM vQualScoringGrade
               ) p
              PIVOT 
              (
                 SUM([Value]) 
                 for [Description] IN ( ' + @cols + ' )
              ) AS pvt 
              ORDER BY Period'

execute(@query);
```

The `OrderBy` column is not being used in the outer select or the PIVOT but you include it in the subquery. This column is being used in the grouping that takes place during a PIVOT. If the values are distinct, then you will get multiple rows.

You can easily test this by including the `OrderBy` on the final select list.

Comment: For lack of naming convention the `OrderBy` is actually a data field and not a `SQL` command.

Comment: @Risho Right, I see that the `OrderBy` is a column in your view. I would use `SortOrder` instead to not get confused. But if that column has a distinct value then you will get multiple rows.